# Xiaomy (Redmi 4x) not synchronizing Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, redmi

I have a Xiaomi phone and almost since the beginning the calendar had sync problems. Until now they were most up to 1 week sync delay but now it stopped sync for good... I've tried to reset the phone, delete and reset the Google account, free up some internal memory space but nothing seems to work.
This problem happens both on the native Xiaomi App and the Google Calendar App so I believe the calendar sync is the problem itself.
The settings sync menu says it was updated today but no events show on the calendar...

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**
After a new reboot the Google Calendar App started to work so I'm sticking with this App but if anyone can solve the Xiaomi Calendar issue please post an answer here.

**DATA**
Model: Xiaomi Redmi 4X
Android version: 7.1.2 N2G47H
MIUI version: 10.3.1.0 (NAMMIXM)